# How to determine if asp.net core has been installed on a windows server

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm setting up various windows servers to host asp.net core apps, and I need to be able to determine if they have the asp.net hosting bundle installed.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle says:

> "Install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle on the server.
>   The bundle will install the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and
>   the ASP.NET Core Module. The module creates the reverse-proxy between
>   IIS and the Kestrel server."

I'm setting up a deployment, and I need to make sure my server is configured so I can run asp.net core apps.

I'm looking, basically, for a registry key or some other way to tell me if I should run the installer setup. (something like the way we'd tell if older versions of the framework are installed, like 
`https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318785`
does for earlier versions)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use powershell to check if the hosting module is registered with IIS

In the local powershell session

```
Import-module WebAdministration
$vm_dotnet_core_hosting_module = Get-WebGlobalModule | where-object { $_.name.ToLower() -eq "aspnetcoremodule" }
if (!$vm_dotnet_core_hosting_module)
{
    throw ".Net core hosting module is not installed"
}
```

If you want to do in the remote session replace first 2 lines with

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Import-module WebAdministration}
$vm_dotnet_core_hosting_module = Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Get-WebGlobalModule | where-object { $_.name.ToLower() -eq "aspnetcoremodule" }}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but having struggles with which of 64bit vs the 32bit powershell's get launched

Comment: How to execute this?

Comment: this is only ok if you don't care which version is installed...

Comment: This command doesn't show the module even after it is installed. For me, this is because the module is actually called `AspNetCoreModuleV2`.

Answer (score 39):

You can search `Microsoft .NET Core 1.1.1 - Windows Server Hosting` registry key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\.NET Core` path like screenshot below.

[image]

Also you can use PowerShell to determine the whether the key existed or not.

```
$DotNETCoreUpdatesPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\.NET Core"
$DotNetCoreItems = Get-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Path $DotNETCoreUpdatesPath
$NotInstalled = $True
$DotNetCoreItems.GetSubKeyNames() | Where { $_ -Match "Microsoft .NET Core.*Windows Server Hosting" } | ForEach-Object {
    $NotInstalled = $False
    Write-Host "The host has installed $_"
}
If ($NotInstalled) {
    Write-Host "Can not find ASP.NET Core installed on the host"
}
```

And you can download sample from [How to determine ASP.NET Core installation on a Windows Server by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-determine-ASPNET-512379b5).

Comment: If it is not installed, "Get-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Path $DotNETCoreUpdatesPath" will error and the script will never finish. The script needs to be surrounded by a try catch to work. I can edit the answer to include that if you like.

Comment: Or, we can use Test-Path to check if $DotNETCoreUpdatesPath exists: $NotInstalled = $True 
$DotNETCoreUpdatesPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\.NET Core" 
if (Test-Path $DotNETCoreUpdatesPath)
{
$DotNetCoreItems = Get-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Path $DotNETCoreUpdatesPath 
$NotInstalled = $True 
$DotNetCoreItems.GetSubKeyNames() | Where { $_ -Match "Microsoft .NET Core.*Windows Server Hosting" } | ForEach-Object { 
    $NotInstalled = $False 
    Write-Host "The host has installed $_" 
} 
(...)

Comment: Not working for me for latest versions of the framework

Comment: I looked at programs and features to find Microsoft .NET 6.0.8 - Windows Server Hosting. This did not appear in the indicated registry location.

Comment: Check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\.NET`

Answer (score 15):

If you have .NET Core CLI installed, you can try:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

Which will print something like:

> Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [c:\program files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [c:\program files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Reference: [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows)

Comment: having a runtime on the machine does not mean IIS module has been installed

Answer (score 4):

If you're allowed to introduce constraints, one option is to only allow "Self-contained applications" since they do not require any additional installs. This also makes issues like 'what version is installed' go away.

If you need to support 'portable apps' you could simply execute the following to check if dotnet.exe is available:

`where dotnet`

You can then check the version:

`dotnet --version`

This would also allow you to check the version of .NET Core once that becomes a concern.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the commands need to be run in powershell as Administrator.

Using the [IISAdministration powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets) all modules can be listed as follows:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration

(Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.webServer/globalModules" `
| Get-IISConfigCollection).GetCollection() `
| select @{n="name";e={$_.GetAttributeValue("name")}}, `
         @{n="image";e={$_.GetAttributeValue("image")}}, `
         @{n="preCondition";e={$_.GetAttributeValue("preCondition")}}
```

So a test could be e.g.

```
$coreModule =
(Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.webServer/globalModules" `
| Get-IISConfigCollection).GetCollection() `
| where {$_.GetAttributeValue("name") -eq "AspNetCoreModuleV2" }

if (-not $coreModule)
{
    throw 'AspNetCoreModuleV2 is not installed'
}
```

Note at the time of this writing, both `AspNetCoreModule` and `AspNetcoreModuleV2` are listed separately. Additional versions will likely show up in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can also double click DotNetCore.1.0.1-WindowsHosting.exe
If the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle is already installed, the opening window will have :

1. Modify Setup label
2. Repair and Uninstall buttons

Repair and Uninstall buttons and a Modify Setup label.
[image: Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - Windows Server Hosting Setup already installed]

Comment: Nice - no need to muck around with the registry or powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{ab4f6e29-67a1-47d9-b2ab-43348a9bbae4}

and make sure that "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - Windows Server Hosting" is there

Comment: This will only detect that a specific installer was used... Probably it will no longer work when the next update is available.

Comment: That's correct, I assume it will work along the same lines as detecting legacy .net versions:  you grovel around in the registry looking for specific keys for specific versions of the framework.