# How do I configure a .net core API to work in IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, deployment, iis-7, .net-core

I've got a .net core API created in Visual Studio 2017 that's working fine.  When I go to deploy it I get error message HTTP Error 500.19 with error code 0x8007000d.  I've found multiple solutions online such as making sure windows features are installed, removing the .net CLR version, changing the application pool identity, changes to web.config and applicationHost.config, but nothing has worked.  Is there a way to definitively find what the problem is or am I stuck doing trial and error with the myriad of possible solutions?  Any specific solutions you know of?

Here are screenshots of the IIS settings and my Windows features:

[image]

Here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*"
        modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
                arguments=".\DishbooksAPI.dll" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
                forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here's the IIS error:

[image]

Some stackoverflow pages I've tried (this is not an exhaustive list):

[HTTP Error 500.19 when publish .net core project into iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805402/http-error-500-19-when-publish-net-core-project-into-iis)

[HTTP Error 500.19 with Error Code 0x8007000d visual studio 2017 while deploying .net core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889736/http-error-500-19-with-error-code-0x8007000d-visual-studio-2017-while-deploying)

[ASP.NET: HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error 0x8007000d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d)

[HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error web config .net core web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049796/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-web-config-net-core-web-api)

[asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Comment: Set `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` in web.config and check whats getting logged in log file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.19 with Error Code 0x8007000d visual studio 2017 while deploying .net core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889736/http-error-500-19-with-error-code-0x8007000d-visual-studio-2017-while-deploying)

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you need to install ***[ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1)*** in web server. 
Here is the [download link](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting).

Then install either ***[SDK or Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)*** in web server.

**Trouble Shooting**

If it still doesn't work, open a command prompt. Navigate to the web application folder and type `dotnet YOUR_APP.dll`. You should see something like this -

```
C:\APIs> dotnet YOUR_APP.dll
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\APIs
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started: Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

It means your application can run in the web server without IIS. Then you need to trouble shoot in IIS or some other things.

Answer (score 1):

You would need the hosting bundle to be installed on IIS

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core

Steps :

1. click the preferred version
2. Search for 'Hosting Bundle' word (should be on the right side)
3. Install the same
4. re-start IIS. And validate your site and see the magic

Why Hosting bundle is needed? Check following article
 https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/23/hosting-an-asp-net-core-web-application-in-iis/

How to check if hosting is installed? 
[How to determine if asp.net core has been installed on a windows server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567796/how-to-determine-if-asp-net-core-has-been-installed-on-a-windows-server)

Comment: How do I "validate my site"?