# ASP.NET web.config HTTP Error 500.19 Throughing error on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, config

This is the first time I have launched an ISS Windows Server 2016 and an ASP.NET application.

Any clues on what is needed to be done to get this app running?

[image]

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Here is my `web.config` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Groliapp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />

    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 06d4355d-1388-4f21-88d8-c0b4afb3c673-->
```

Comment: This error can be a red herring.  You'll often see it when there's nothing wrong with your web.config file.  Check to be sure you have installed .net-core.  Often you assume that .net is enough, but you need to download/install .net-core specifically.

Comment: @pcalkins You are my hero! Thank you! It worked! Now I just have to debug the program to get the database connection working properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure a .net core API to work in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612351/how-do-i-configure-a-net-core-api-to-work-in-iis)

Answer (score -1):

Usually when you do not have the .NET Core Runtime installed in your server, this error could happen.
Did you already install the .NET Core Runtime in your server?
In case you did not installed yet, here is the link to download.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/current/runtime

Comment: How this resolve the issue. Why this would be required. Elaborate and give a reason.