# Blazor WebAssembly Hosted internal server error

Tags: iis, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I tried to deploy sample project exists in Blazor WebAssembly Hosted application. I published the server app and tried to run it using `.exe` file. It worked fine. But when I tried to deploy it in IIS, It shows the following error:

[image]

I studied the same post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217112/blazor-hosted-asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error) but I could not find any solution for my case.
I have installed latest .NET 7 hosting bundle.
How can I fix it?

**Update:**
[image]

Comment: IIS cannot access folders of a user by default. You need to grant IIS_IUSRS the necessary permissions. Examples can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights#inetpubwwwroot

Comment: I had a similar issue and I was able to fix this by pointing my application to the directory which contains the index page (wwwroot) instead of the one which contains the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lex said, the IIS_IUSRS group doesn't have the appropriate permissions for the ApplicationHost.config file, the Web.config file, or the virtual or application directories of IIS. Try to grant full permissions to user "IIS_IUSRS".
Refer to this official document about HTTP error 500.19 HRESULT code 0x80070005: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x80070005.

This error can also happen if the site is configured to use the IIS URL Rewrite module but it is not installed. If the same problem still occurs after granting permissions, please try the solutions provided by community members under this answer: [IIS 500.19 with 0x80070005 The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/iis-500-19-with-0x80070005-the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-rel?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top).